# Ruby - Reduce array of numbers in ruby returns strange result

Tags: ruby, mapreduce, keyword-argument, splat

I'm trying to write a method called `calculate` which determine to `add` or `subtract` numbers depending on a keyword argument passed to it.

Here're the methods:

```
def add(*num)
  num.inject(:+)
end

def subtract(*num)
  num.reduce(:-)
end

def calculate(*num, **op)
  return add(num) if op[:add] || op.empty?
  return subtract(num) if op[:subtract]
end

puts calculate(1, 2, 3, add: true)
puts calculate(1, 2, 3, subtract: true)
```

When I run this function, I get this result:

```
1
2
3

1
2
3
```

Comment: @sawa Is it done using splat only and extracting the last element ? Sorry I'm quite new to Ruby

Comment: If you follow my advise, then your method will be simply `def calculate *args, op; args.inject(case op; when :add then :+; when :subtract then :- end) end`.

Comment: Or, if you decide you can go with `calculate(1, 2, 3, :+)`, `calculate(1, 2, 3, :-)`, then it would be `def calculate *args, op; args.inject(op) end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puts` is your friend:

```
def add(*num)
  puts "in add, num = #{num}, num.size = #{num.size}"
  num.inject(:+)
end

def calculate(*num, **op)
  puts "num = #{num}, op = #{op}"
  return add(num) if op[:add] || op.empty?
end

calculate(1, 2, 3, add: true)
  # num = [1, 2, 3], op = {:add=>true}
  # in add, num = [[1, 2, 3]], num.size = 1
  #=> nil
```

Now fix `calculate`:

```
def calculate(*num, **op)
  puts "num = #{num}, op = #{op}"
  return add(*num) if op[:add] || op.empty?
end

calculate(1, 2, 3, add: true)
  # num = [1, 2, 3], op = {:add=>true}
  # in add, num = [1, 2, 3], num.size = 3
  # => 6
```

Comment: But can you tell me why in `calculate` method body, replacing `add(num)` with `add(*num)` solved it ?

Comment: Say `a = [1,2,3]`. `add` adds its arguments together, so : `add(*a) => add(1,2,3) => 6`. With `add(a)`, `add` has only one argument, the array `a`. When one or more arrays are passed as arguments to `add`, `arr.inject(:+)` uses [Array#+](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B), not [Fixnum#+](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B): `add([1,2],[3,4]) => [1, 2, 3, 4] `,  `add([1,2]) => [1, 2] `. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

You write :

```
return add(*num) if opt[:add] || opt.empty?
```

Same way modify the return subtract.. Part too.

With your posted code num becomes [[1,2,3]], and thus [[1,2,3]].inject(:+) gives return the receiver back. And you called puts on it, so it outputs like as you got.

Comment: Hmmm, It seems to work now. But could you please elaborate why passing `*num` works and passing `num` doesn't as I showed above ?

Comment: I m on Mobil just give me some moment.